# How to fix width for all the download buttons in shinyApp?

Tags: css, r, button, shiny, shinydashboard

I have some downloadbuttons in a column, in shinyApp.
I want to fix the same width for all the downloadbuttons in that column.

I don't know how to do it. I have tried css with `tags$style(".btn: { vertical-align: middle; height: 50px; width: 150%; font-size: 30px;}")`

```
mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel(
column(tags$style(".btn: { vertical-align: middle; height: 50px; width: 
150%; font-size: 30px;}")
downloadButton("sadoon", "Sadoon_D"),                             
downloadButton("sahoo", "Sahoo_D"),                             
downloadButton("sainj", "Sainj_D"),                             
downloadButton("salooni", "Salooni_D")))))
```

[image]

I expect the downloadbuttons should be in the same width, but the output is as in the attached image.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Delete `:` after `.btn`. So it will be something like: `tags$head(tags$style(".btn { vertical-align: middle; height: 50px; width: 
150%; font-size: 30px;}"))`

Comment: Thank a lot. You are great..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete `:` after `.btn`. 
So it will be something like:

```
tags$head(
   tags$style("
    .btn { vertical-align: middle; height: 50px; width: 150%; font-size: 30px;}"
))
```